# All services of a user are killed when running multiple services under this user with systemd

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

We're using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and want to use multiple Tomcat installations which should start at boot time. One of these Tomcats would host a Jenkins which will deploy a webapp onto the other tomcat and restart it.

To start the services, we added systemd service scripts. 
What we noticed is that when one tomcat is stopped or killed, the other is stopped as well.

We reduced this to two simple scripts that only use /usr/bin/yes:

**Unit A**

```
[Unit]
Description=A
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/yes
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat8
Group=tomcat8

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Unit B**

```
[Unit]
Description=B
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

ExecStart=/usr/bin/yes
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat8
Group=tomcat8

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What happens:
When a service is killed (`kill -9`), both services are gone afterwards.

1. Why are both services killed? How can we prevent this?
2. Is running more than one service under a single user discouraged, or is this good practice?

**EDIT:** For clarification - we did also try to do the same when launching the tomcats without systemd. In this instance, the behaviour was as expected: only the killed service was stopped while the other lived on.

**EDIT2:** The user is not a front-end user that logs in/out at all. It's purely a system user to restrict access of the services.

Comment: see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394 (on both -why- and -what to do-.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/e81f253/NEWS#L50) for systemd (v230) says:

> systemd-logind will now by default terminate user processes that are
>             part of the user session scope unit (session-XX.scope) when the user
>             logs out. This behavior is controlled by the KillUserProcesses=
>             setting in logind.conf, and the previous default of "no" is now
>             changed to "yes". This means that user sessions will be properly
>             cleaned up after, but additional steps are necessary to allow
>   intentionally long-running processes to survive logout.

So this is default behaviour.  It also explains what to do to undo the change: `logind.conf`, set `KillUserProcesses=` to `no` (and 
`--without-kill-user-processes option` to `configure`)

But the changelog also includes a ...

> While the user is logged in at least once, `user@.service` is running,
>             and any service that should survive the end of any individual login
>             session can be started at a user service or scope using `systemd-run`.
>             systemd-run(1) man page has been extended with an example which shows
>             how to run screen in a scope unit underneath `user@.service`. The same
>   command works for tmux.

and

> After the user logs out of all sessions, user@.service will be
>             terminated too, by default, unless the user has `lingering` enabled.
>             To effectively allow users to run long-term tasks even if they are
>             logged out, lingering must be enabled for them. **See loginctl(1) for
>             details. The default polkit policy was modified to allow users to
>   set lingering for themselves without authentication**.

That one is more important since it uses the default (kill'm all) with a way to provide exceptions: enable `lingering`.

Some more info:

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394

Comment: I'll see if I can try to disable the ProcessKilling in `logind.conf`. I am unsure though why that should happen, as the user the service runs as is not the one we login with, but basically a system user. In that sense, he neither logs in or out...
Do you see an explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `systemd` dependency arrangement.

It sounds like this [shutdown logic](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) may be happening:

> when two units with an ordering dependency between them are shut down,
>   the inverse of the start-up order is applied. i.e. if a unit is
>   configured with After= on another unit, the former is stopped before
>   the latter if both are shut down.

However, your sample script don't show that you've create a dependency between one and the other.

I tried running your sample "A" script, and it didn't start:

```
 Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/yes: No such process
```

( I tested on Ubuntu 16.04 ).

Comment: Hm. I don't know why you don't have the yes-binary. It is part of coreutils: http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/coreutils/filelist

Comment: Strangely, I *do* have the yes binary, and it is located at `/usr/bin/yes`. Perhaps it's not in the `systemd` path.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that if you check the `status` of the service after starting it that you are certain you've checked the service is "running" before you test killing one of them.

Comment: Yes, I checked: `systemctl status [servicename]` shows it is active, the pid of the process and I can see it using ps.